# clickhosue jinja looping config.xml.j2

Tags: for-loop, ansible, jinja2, clickhouse, ansible-template

i have this list of ansible inventory

```
[clickhouse]
server01 ansible_host=10.1.1.1 name=server01 
server02 ansible_host=10.1.1.2 name=server02
server03 ansible_host=10.1.1.3 name=server03 
server04 ansible_host=10.1.1.4 name=server04
```

i have this config.xml.j2

```
   <noc>
      <shard>
        <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
        <replica>
            <host>server01 </host>
            <port>9000</port>
        </replica>
        <replica>
            <host>server02</host>
            <port>9000</port>
        </replica>        
      </shard>
    </noc>
```

**can you support with looping to be like the below **
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaSm6.png)

Comment: i dont understant what is your problem and what you have tested

Comment: i want to do loop for the config when it find 4 server under inventory create new replica

Comment: can you check the image thats want i want

Comment: your list is using 2 hosts at each loop?

Comment: yes for example server01  and server02 then server03 server04

Comment: you got my point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create `config.xml.j2` file in templates folder:

```
   <noc>
   {% for i in  range(0, (ansible_play_hosts_all) | length , 2) %}
      <shard>
        <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
        <replica>
            <host>{{ ansible_play_hosts_all[i] }}</host>
            <port>9000</port>
        </replica>
        <replica>
            <host>{{ ansible_play_hosts_all[i | int + 1] }}</host>
            <port>9000</port>
        </replica>        
      </shard>
    {% endfor %}
    </noc>
```

and use it with this playbook:

```
- name: "tips4"
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks: 
    - name: Include vars
      template:
        src: config.xml.j2
        dest: config.xml
      delegate_to: localhost
```

following the version of ansible you have, you could write

`ansible_play_hosts_all[i + 1]` instead of `ansible_play_hosts_all[i | int + 1]`

Comment: i can't run in specific group  [clickhouse]
 ?

Comment: i should run at all ?

Comment: you could use groups["clickhouse"] instead of ansible_play_hosts_all